# PHP class_exists always returns true

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that needs some pre-defined globals before the file is included:

File: includes/Product.inc.php

```
if (class_exists('Product')) {
    return;
}

// This class requires some predefined globals
if ( !isset($gLogger) || !isset($db) || !isset($glob) ) {
    return;
}

class Product
{
   ...
}
```

The above is included in other PHP files that need to use Product using **require_once**. Anyone who wants to use Product must however ensure those globals are available, at least that's the idea.

I recently debugged an issue in a function within the Product class which was caused because $gLogger was null. The code requiring the above Product.inc.php had not bothered to create the $gLogger. So The question is how was this class ever included if $gLogger was null?

I tried to debug the code (xdebug in NetBeans), put a breakpoint at the start of Product.inc.php to find out and every time it came to the if (class_exists('Product')) clause it would simply step in and return thus never getting to the global checks. So how was it ever included the first time?

This is PHP 5.1+ running under MAMP (Apache/MySQL). I don't have any auto loaders defined.

> Thanks for the informative answers guys. My belief was that when you
>   include a file PHP starts executing it line by line from line one, so
>   it would not allow me to include the file if the globals were not
>   defined. I will move the checks into the constructor. Based on the
>   original question, I accept the answer from @deceze

Comment: The class is declared right there, so it exists

Comment: BTW, you can use `!isset($gLogger, $db, $glob)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is *parsed* before it is executed. Classes are "loaded" by parsing, but functions are executed after the parsing. By putting the function call in the same file as the class, the class is always parsed and "loaded" before that function executes, thereby it's always `true`.

If you are always including the file using `require_once` (which is good), there's no point in that check anyway. A class definition shouldn't conditionally depend on some global variables. Rethink what you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks, then how do I get the wanted behaviour, that Product cant be included (require_onced) unless the globals have been defined?

Comment: Rethink what you're doing here. If at all, make the class ***instantiation*** depend on globals, but not the ***definition***. Better, don't make it depend on globals at all. Pass those as parameters into the class and have other code check whether you want to instantiate the class or not.

Comment: What do you **really** intend to achieve? Do you really need to keep the class definition outside your code or do you just wanna limit the creation of instances until your verifications are met?

Comment: Yes, I want to limit the creation of instances until my verifications are met. Product cant function without those globals. I know globals are bad etc, but this is legacy code and we are improving it gradually.

Comment: @Ali Then throw an Exception in the class constructor when you try to instantiate it when conditions aren't met.

Comment: @Ali: I have two examples in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13268449/367456 - The first shows you how to check on instantiate (if that are your legacy needs), the second with dependency injection how you should do it. As you have got legacy needs, I show you another third way to make this a good seam.

Answer (score 2):

I see a main issue here:

```
// This class requires some predefined globals
```

That might be surprising to you, but I think what you actually want to do is, that if that is the case, you don't check that when you define the class, but when you instantiate it.

When a class is instantiated, it's constructor function is called. This seems like the perfect place to me to check for that:

```
class Product
{
    public function __construct() {
        // This class requires some predefined globals
        $this->needGlobal('gLogger', 'db', 'glob');
    }

    private function needGlobal() {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $global) {
            if (!isset($GLOBALS[$global])) {
                throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Global %s needed but not set.', $global));
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

When you instantiate a `Product` it then automatically checks if the preconditions are met:

```
$blueShoes = new Product();
```

This will not work if the pre-conditions are not met, but it will work if.

But that is only partially solving your problem. The real problem with your code is that the `Product` *needs* global variables to work.

Instead make the product just take the things it needs to work with:

```
class Product
{
    private $gLogger;
    private $db;
    private $glob;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $gLogger, DbInterface $db, GlobInterface $glob) {
        $this->gLogger = $gLogger;
        $this->db      = $db;
        $this->glob    = $glob;
    }    

    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
$redShoes = new Product($gLogger, $db, $glob);
```

And then you don't need to care about anything global inside `Product` any longer.

---

You commented you want to gradually improve the code. You can do so, here is how. As written the second variant above is the way to go, but currently the legacy code is not compatible with it. In any case if the `Product` class is new code, you should write it with dependency injection. This is important to separate the legacy code from the new code. You don't want to have the legacy stuff swallowed by your new code. That would make new code legacy code, so you would not be able to gradually improve. You would just add new legacy code.

So take the class definition with the dependency injection. For your legacy needs write a second class that is shielding this:

```
class ProductLegacy extends Product
{
    public function __construct() {
        // This class requires some predefined globals
        list($gLogger, $db, $glob) = $this->needGlobal('gLogger', 'db', 'glob');
        parent::__construct($gLogger, $db, $glob);
    }

    private function needGlobal() {
        $variables = array();
        foreach (func_get_args() as $global) {
            if (!isset($GLOBALS[$global])) {
                throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Global %s needed but not set.', $global));
            }
            $variables[] = $GLOBALS[$global];
        }
        return $variables;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this little stub brings together the global way of doing things with the new way. You can use the `Product` class in your new code, and if you need to interface with old code, you use the `ProductLegacy` class that works with the global variables for class instantiation.

You could also create a helper function that is doing this, so you can use it for different classes. Depends a bit on your needs. Just find a border where you can draw a clear line between old code and new code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I know having Product need globals is bad, but there are lots of classes and all of them need those globals. So passing them to every class constructor makes the overall code more difficult to read. $product = new Product($id) seems like a cleaner API?

Comment: You should separate your needs here. If `Product` and perhaps a lot of *similar* classes share a common base, you can make them share a base class. Additionally you can create a factory object for these that is dealing with initializing them properly: `$factory = new Factory($gLogger, $db, $glob);` and then `$redShoes = $factory->make($id);`. That is clean API, less globals, more streamlined code = less errors.